# Using singleton class in Sharepoint2010 environment - webapplication wide?

Tags: c#, web-applications, sharepoint-2010, singleton, sitecollection

Let's say I have one web-application with n SiteCollections. 
Now I have a feature, which includes a singleton class. Does every SiteCollection have their own context and their own Instance of this class or is the singleton "Web-Application-Wide"?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found it on my own: Yes, the singelton is the same for every site-collection, because there are all running in the same iis application-pool.